# Backbone Marionette routing does not work for nested routes

Tags: marionette

I am trying to learn Backbone Marionette. I have created a sample application here. I am using jquery, bootstrap, requirejs, backbone, marionette etc.

My routing configuration is like:

```
appRoutes: {
    "": "index",
    "done/:id": "done"
}
```

First route for main page works fine. However second route does not work if I try to navigate to say `localhost:8001/#done/2`. Again it works when I try to navigate to say `localhost:8001/##done/2`. [Observe ## here]

Appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 1):

Can't say for sure, but try setting your routes as

```
appRoutes: {
  "index": "index",
  "done/:id": "done"
}
```

My influence is too low to comment, but if you also could tell me how it is failing at #done/2 (i.e. is it just loading the main page?)

**EDIT**

Is backbone.history.started?
I use coffeescript and use this:

```
App.on "start", ->
  Backbone.history.start() unless Backbone.history.started
```

Comment: Yes. it is just loading the main page. Server should not get a call if you click #someUri

Comment: Any errors in the console? (Ctrl + shift + c in chrome)